# Missing file in my Dockerfile, whats the path its running from?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

My git repo structure

```
app
- app.server
  - server files
- app.client
  - node_modules
  - public
  - src
  - .dockerignore
  - Dockerfile
  - package.json
  - package-log.json
```

I've set up CI/CD with GitHub actions but something is wrong in my Dockerimage for my client application (React)?

Error message: `COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist`

My .dockeringore file:

```
node_modules
build
.dockerignore
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.prod
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app.client

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app.client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY ./ ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My GitHub action command for invoking the Dockerfile:

```
docker build app.client/ -t mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/appdb:${{ github.sha }}
```

This is part of a publish to Azure Container registry that I'm trying to learn. I guess the Dockerfile works, because before failing at step 4/9 it goes thru the Dockerfile:

```
Step 1/9 : FROM node:13.12.0-alpine
13.12.0-alpine: Pulling from library/node
aad63a933944: Pulling fs layer
... (and so on)
Step 3/6 : COPY package.json ./
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: How do you build your image?

Comment: What does `.dockerignore` contain (ignore)?

Comment: how do you invoke docker? looks like you are not in the right directory. Would be best to be explicit by using some pipelines variables that point to the repo as context instead of just a dot or something.

Comment: "*whats the path its running from?*" - the last argument of a `docker build ...` command is either a path, an URL or a `-` and specifies the build context (see the [`docker build` manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description)). In most cases, we use `.`, i.e. the current directory, as build context. This is the path that is used to resolve all paths from the Dockerfile that define docker-host resources.

Comment: I've added the command for building the image

Comment: The command seems off. Can you try moving the `-t ...` in front of `app.client`?

Comment: Same error @Turing85

Comment: What does `./app.client/.dockerignore` contain?

Comment: Its listed in my post @DazWilkin

Comment: Apologies, missed it!

Comment: @Turing85 your comment was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`WORKDIR` refers to the working directory in the *container*. The working directory on the host is still the root of your repo.

Comment: "*The working directory on the host is still the root of your repo.*" - That's an assumption :) as long as we do not see the `docker build ...` command, we cannot be sure what the context directory is.